# HTML Canvas silently drops frames (requestAnimationFrame)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've found that canvas + javascript is silently dropping frames when using requestAnimationFrame() (tested on Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 (64-bit)). Most surprisingly, getImageData shows the correct color values even when a frame did not display.

The code below should display a white flash every sixty frames, or one second for 60Hz monitors. But sometimes, the console displays 'flash' even when no white flash is displayed. Any thoughts on what is going on and how to detect if a frame drops?

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("flicker")
var context = canvas.getContext("2d")

canvas.width  = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight

let i = 0
let displayFlash = false

// once per second
function renderLoop() {
    if (i%60 == 0) {
        console.log("flash")
        displayFlash = true
        context.fillStyle = "white"
    } else if (displayFlash) {
    // try to verify frame was displayed
        if (context.getImageData(1,1,1,1).data[0]===255) {
        displayFlash = false
        context.fillStyle = "black"
        }  else {
        context.fillStyle = "white"
      }

    } else {
        context.fillStyle = "black"
    }
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);       
    i++
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop)
}

renderLoop()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tbenst/gdbsb564/5

Edit: fixed jsfiddle link

Comment: I find your code does nothing

Comment: if you can't see the flash but flash is logged how is this a "dropped frame" just because your eyes didn't detect a flash

Comment: @JaromandaX apologies, I dropped the version on the jsfiddle link. it should work now. On my computer (2013 core i5), it drops 20% of flashes. When tested on a 6-core i7 + gtx 1070 it drops about 1% of frames. 16ms of white light is detectable by our eyes

Comment: I have a core i5-3470 with a GT 630 video card - so, well below your specs. And there's no "missing" flashes - perhaps it's your monitor - though, I only tested using Firefox, will test in Chrum 54 now

Comment: Nope, Chrum is fine as well

Comment: I can repro on 54.0 and 56 canary on osX. We can see a white ghost on the right when not covering the whole canvas : https://jsfiddle.net/gdbsb564/7/ That should probably be reported, and maybe is related to [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=647903&can=2&q=Canvas%20alpha%20false%20white&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) => [no alpha](https://jsfiddle.net/gdbsb564/8/)

Comment: @Kaiido Glad you can reproduce. I also see weird behavior on your jsfiddle: on some frames I see only a vertical line of pixels on the right edge of where the rectangle should fill. Curiously this happens in both chrome and firefox on Linux. I did a quick test on Windows and did not see any missed flashes